# Write Image in a Python Bluemix Server

Tags: python, opencv, flask, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to save a image after a process with opencv in a Python Blumix server but an error occurs. I'm reading a local image that I upload when push the app, but I can't write in the same location.

```
image = cv2.imread('static/images/image.jpg') #works

# do some process to the image...

cv2.imwrite('static/images/processed.jpg', processed_image) #works in local but not in server
```

Do I need some permissions? Special folder? The server is read only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error ? if any or simply it is silently failing to write the image ?

Comment: Hi @ZdaR thanks for your comment, The flask server throws a 502 error, so i debugged line by line, and only fails when try to write the image

Comment: Do you really want to store the image here?  This location will only give you  ephemeral storage.

Comment: Hi @ChrisSnow, I need the image for a couple of minutes for another process with Javascript. if get erased  after doesn't matter. The process is: Upload an image->process the image with opencv---> save the processed image-->acces with javascript to the processed image--->return results

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look to using object storage for the image.  This will give you more options if you want to later split your code into microservices.  Using local storage is also not advised:

> **Avoid Writing to the Local File System**
>
> Applications running on Cloud
> Foundry should not write files to the local file system for the
> following reasons:
>
> - Local file system storage is short-lived. When an application instance
>   crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are
>   reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since
>   the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will
>   start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local
>   files while it is running, the files will disappear after the
>   application restarts.
> - Instances of the same application do not share a
>   local file system. Each application instance runs in its own isolated
>   container. Thus a file written by one instance is not visible to other
>   instances of the same application. If the files are temporary, this
>   should not be a problem. However, if your application needs the data
>   in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs
>   to be shared across all running instances of the application, the
>   local file system should not be used. We recommend using a shared data
>   service like a database or blobstore for this purpose.
>
> *Source: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem*